# first record should be selected when loading the data in advance datagrid

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3

I have a advanced datagrid and displying the 10 records. but when loading the data, the first record should be selected. Can you please help me how to do it.

Thanks,
Ravi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `dataProvider` is updated dynamically, just call `grid.selectedIndex = 0;` after updating it. Otherwise, call it from the `creationComplete` handler.

Comment: @Thanks Amar: Yes, Dataprovider is updated dynamically. so i need to call gridId.selectIndex=0; and when data selected, charts has to be updated based on the selected data.pls forward the sample code lines, if have.

Comment: @Ravi `gridId.selectIndex=0;` is all you need. Call it after you set the data provider.